# SSH executes `Match exec` lines from conditionally excluded includes

Tags: ssh, documentation

I stumbled across this behavior and was wondering if it is intended and/or documented, because I could not find anything.

The manpage of my version of ssh states for `ssh_config` / `Include`:

> Include directive may appear inside a Match or Host block to perform conditional inclusion.

Given the following files:

```
# ~/.ssh/config

Host doesnotexist.nonexistanttld
  Include ~/.ssh/inc
```

```
# ~/.ssh/inc
Match host * exec "touch do-not-touch"
```

I can observe this:

```
$ ssh foo
ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
$ ls
do-not-touch
```

The reason for this seems to be this:

```
debug3: $HOME/.ssh/config line 2: Including file $HOME/.ssh/inc depth 0 (parse only)
debug2: checking match for 'host * exec "touch do-not-touch"' [...]
```

(notice the `parse only`)

I would not expect this to happen. So again, is this intended? Is there a good reason for this versus only reading and parsing and executing matches in actually included files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, like in many other configuration file syntaxes, the `Include` directive and your `Include ~/.ssh/inc` is not actually 100% conditional, (despite your indentation and the manual ). But rather that the config parser first includes any and all (nested)  configuration snippets into a single effective configuration (effectively substituting the `Include file_name` line with the contents of `file_name` ) and only then evaluates that merged configuration file.

The merged result for your example would  be

```
Host doesnotexist.nonexistanttld
Match host * exec "touch do-not-touch"
```

A `Host` directive restricts the subsequent configuration directives up to the next `Host` or `Match` directive, and therefore there are no specific settings for doesnotexist.nonexistanttld  and `exec "touch do-not-touch"` will be executed for every host.

This Q&A reports the same by the way https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/734537

Comment: What confused me is the string "parse only", which does not appear on `Include`s that are unconditional or where the condition is true. But you are right, there is no real nesting in ssh_config, so the behavior is not as unexpected as I made it out to be. And thanks for the link, I completely missed that.